# How to make one pdf from many pdfs where their filename are also shown in the one pdf?

Tags: pdf

I have a directory named `Titlepage` where the files(minimum 10 pdf) are `titlepage_1.pdf`,`titlepage_2.pdf`,`titlepage_3.pdf`... . Each are one page pdf.

This directory also hosted in Github so that people can download the title pages easily. The Github directory contains corresponding LaTeX file also.

I want to make a combined pdf using these where each page contain 4 pdfs. And each title page also have their original name.  So that anybody can choose a pdf by comparing all in one pdf and then download what title page he needs.

[I guess it can be done using `pdfuite`. And if not possible using only `pdfunite` then combining with `LaTeX`]

[image]

or

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expl3,graphicx,url}
\newcommand\addpage[1]{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr.5\linewidth}{%
      \centering%
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{#1}}\\%
      \path{#1}%
  }%
  \penalty0\relax
}
\lineskip=0pt plus 1fil
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{100}{
  \file_if_exist:nT{titlepage_#1.pdf}{
    \addpage{titlepage_#1.pdf}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

This works exact my requirement. I got this code in my laptop. This is actually not my own code. I collected this from someone in the online, but I can't remember. Thank you, the anonymous helper.

Comment: Bear in mind that this "enlarges" the pages, meaning that the borders drawn around your pages are wider than the physical pages are. Also there is an unnecessary `\dimexpr` in the argument of `\parbox`.

Answer (score 1):

The order doesn't match yours, but the following puts the specified pages into one pdf (using LaTeX):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\putTitlepage[1]
  {%
    \bgroup
    \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
    \noindent
    \fbox{%
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]
        {#1}%
    }\\%
    \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \egroup
  }

\newcount\myTPcounter

\makeatletter
\newcommand\putTheTitlepages[1]
  {%
    \@for\cs:={#1}\do
      {%
        \expandafter\putTitlepage\expandafter{\cs}%
        \par
      }%
  }
\newcommand\putTitlepagesPattern[4]
  {%
    \myTPcounter=\numexpr#3-1\relax
    \loop\ifnum\myTPcounter<#4
      \advance\myTPcounter by 1
      \typeout{}%
      \typeout{Now processing file}%
      \typeout{\the\myTPcounter}%
      \typeout{}%
      \expandafter\putTitlepagesPattern@i\expandafter{\the\myTPcounter}{#1}{#2}%
      \par
    \repeat
  }
\newcommand\putTitlepagesPattern@i[3]
  {%
    \putTitlepage{#2#1#3}%
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\centering
% if you need to specify their names because they don't match a pattern
\putTheTitlepages{titlepage-1.pdf,titlepage-2.pdf}

\putTitlepagesPattern{titlepage-}{.pdf}{3}{10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be better if you use loop for adding the pdf. So, when there are more pdf in that directory they can be added just recompiling the code.

Comment: @alhelal it does use a loop for adding the pdfs. But it doesn't check whether the pdfs it tries to include exist. If you want to include more pdfs, change the arguments of `\putTitlepagesPattern`. The last two arguments specify the range in which the included pdf-names are.

Comment: I used your solution long times ago. Now, I am trying to use but failed`. !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./titlepage_1.pdf): reading image file failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/test$ ls
combinepdf.aux  titlepage_1.pdf  titlepage_2.tex  titlepage_4.pdf  titlepage_5.tex
combinepdf.log  titlepage_1.tex  titlepage_3.pdf  titlepage_4.tex  titlepage_6.pdf
combinepdf.tex  titlepage_2.pdf  titlepage_3.tex  titlepage_5.pdf  titlepage_6.tex
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/test$ `

Comment: error message https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/STkrv44jdN/

Comment: @alhelal from the snippet of the output you provide it seems like the file `titlepage_1.pdf` is corrupted in some way. Can you open it separately in a PDF viewer and check whether that one does output any strange messages (so invoke it from Terminal to see whether it complains). If you still have the sources for that file, can you try to recreate it and then again try to include it?

Comment: yes you are right, there was mistake in pdf file